# UINib initWithNibName crash before app load

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit

I have an iOS app that runs fine on the simulator, but crashes on all devices with this error:

```
<Warning>: *** Assertion failure in -[UINib initWithNibName:directory:bundle:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.14/UINib.m:98
Apr 13 23:24:52 Feifan-Zhous-iPad splashboardd[14537]
<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: (name != nil) && ([name length] > 0)'
```

The app is in Swift, running on Xcode 6.1.1. The device here is an iPad Mini 4,4 running iOS 8.1 (but the crash happens on all devices including iPhones, ranging from iOS 7.0 upwards).

Notable is the crash happens before the app launches (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` never gets called) and an exception breakpoint in Xcode doesn't catch anything.

The app uses a `Main.storyboard` file as the Main Interface file. It is **not** red in the Copy Bundle Resources phase. The app isn't using `initWithNibName:directory:bundle` anywhere.

Has anyone run into this error and found a fix? Very little to work on

Comment: Can you give more source code? I think the problem in main storyboard scene or in the class for main storyboard scene. You can set another view controller as initial and look if the application starts normally. Then you can go to broken scene and look in debugger where it crashes...

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? i'm having the same problem, and it's becoming a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

> I have an iOS app that runs fine on the simulator, but crashes on all devices

It looks like it must be something with capitalization of a file name. I suppose that you have installed case insensitive file system on your mac so a simulator treats name "File" as "file" (and even "FILE") while iOS devices has case sensitive file systems so file names are case sensitive.

I suppose that you've set incorrectly class name for your initial view controller and it cannot be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably initializing a nib name in initWithNibName:directory:bundle which isn't ever being called.

Move the your initialization code from initWithNibName:directory:bundle to awakeFromNib.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, check in the `rootViewController/InitialView` if you are registering a nib file with a wrong file/reference name. Had that when I registered `UICollectionViewCells` in `viewDidLoad` while making a network call, didn't show where the crash was.